# CUDA H.264 decoder initialization problems

Tags: cuda, h.264, decoder

I am trying to develop multi-streaming H.264 video player based on cudaDecodeD3D9 example from NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2.

Application works correctly with a few streams but it raises assertion (CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY) in cuvidCreateDecoder function for 12 streams with resolution 800x600 or 9 streams with resolution 1920x1080. cudaMemGetInfo returns 387MB (for video card with 1GB) and 1.3Gb (for video card with 2GB) available memory. Does memory fragmentation cause this? How can I use available memory?

```
VideoDecoder::VideoDecoder(const CUVIDEOFORMAT & rVideoFormat, 
                       CUcontext &rContext, 
                       cudaVideoCreateFlags eCreateFlags, 
                       CUvideoctxlock &vidCtxLock) 
: m_VidCtxLock(vidCtxLock)
{
// get a copy of the CUDA context
m_Context          = rContext;
m_VideoCreateFlags = eCreateFlags;

// Fill the decoder-create-info struct from the given video-format struct.
memset(&oVideoDecodeCreateInfo_, 0, sizeof(CUVIDDECODECREATEINFO));
        // Create video decoder
oVideoDecodeCreateInfo_.CodecType           = rVideoFormat.codec;
oVideoDecodeCreateInfo_.ulWidth             = rVideoFormat.coded_width;
oVideoDecodeCreateInfo_.ulHeight            = rVideoFormat.coded_height;
oVideoDecodeCreateInfo_.ulNumDecodeSurfaces = FrameQueue::cnMaximumSize;

        // Limit decode memory to 24MB (16M pixels at 4:2:0 = 24M bytes)
while (oVideoDecodeCreateInfo_.ulNumDecodeSurfaces * rVideoFormat.coded_width * rVideoFormat.coded_height > 16*1024*1024)
{
    oVideoDecodeCreateInfo_.ulNumDecodeSurfaces--;
}
oVideoDecodeCreateInfo_.ChromaFormat        = rVideoFormat.chroma_format;
oVideoDecodeCreateInfo_.OutputFormat        = cudaVideoSurfaceFormat_NV12;
oVideoDecodeCreateInfo_.DeinterlaceMode     = cudaVideoDeinterlaceMode_Adaptive;

        // No scaling
oVideoDecodeCreateInfo_.ulTargetWidth       = oVideoDecodeCreateInfo_.ulWidth;
oVideoDecodeCreateInfo_.ulTargetHeight      = oVideoDecodeCreateInfo_.ulHeight;
oVideoDecodeCreateInfo_.ulNumOutputSurfaces = MAX_FRAME_COUNT;  // We won't simultaneously map more than 8 surfaces
oVideoDecodeCreateInfo_.ulCreationFlags     = m_VideoCreateFlags;
oVideoDecodeCreateInfo_.vidLock             = m_VidCtxLock;

size_t available, total;
cudaMemGetInfo(&available, &total);

        // create the decoder
CUresult oResult = cuvidCreateDecoder(&oDecoder_, &oVideoDecodeCreateInfo_);
assert(CUDA_SUCCESS == oResult);
}
```

Can cuvidCreateDecoder work with resolution over 1920x1080? When I try 2560x1920 stream cuvidCreateDecoder asserts CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_SOURCE.

#### My environment

- Hardware: NVidia GTX 550 Ti 1Gb, NVidia GT 610 2Gb, driver version 306.23
- Windows 7 x64
- Visual Studio 2010 SP1
- Windows SDK 7.1
- NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit v.4.2, v.5.0
- NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the memory issue, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8686409/749748).

For the question on resolution, Compute Capability 2.0 and earlier GPUs do not support larger than HD resolution for `cudaDecodeD3D9`. This is why you can't decode a 2560x1920 stream.

Kepler GPUs can support much larger resolutions.