# Whatever Cuda function call returns cudaErrorMemoryAllocation

Tags: cuda, out-of-memory, runtime-error

I was wondering why none of simple Cuda code examples I found in Internet are working for me and I found that even this simplest code cause an error:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    size_t available, total;
    cudaError_t err = cudaMemGetInfo(&available, &total);
    if (err == cudaErrorMemoryAllocation) {
        printf("cudaErrorMemoryAllocation");
    } else {
        printf("OK or not memory allocation error");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code above always prints out "cudaErrorMemoryAllocation".

Here is the output of cuda-memcheck test for this program:

```
cudaErrorMemoryAllocation
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= Program hit error 2 on CUDA API call to cudaMemGetInfo 
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\nvcuda.dll (cuD3D11CtxCreate + 0x118a92) [0x137572]
=========     Host Frame:D:\Cuda\a.exe [0x1223]
=========     Host Frame:D:\Cuda\a.exe [0x101c]
=========     Host Frame:D:\Cuda\a.exe [0x901f]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL (BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x1a) [0x1832]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll (RtlUserThreadStart + 0x21) [0x5d609]
=========
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 1 error
```

**Platform** Windows 8 64-bit

**Compiler** Visual Studio 2008

**Compute capability** 1.1 (GeForce 8800 GT)

**CUDA version** 5.5

Comment: Are you able to correctly run the CUDA SDK samples, in particular, the deviceQuery sample?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to run deviceQuery, it prints out the configuration of my 8800 GT correctly. However a few other samples I've tried to launch failed with "CUDA error code=2 (cudaErrorMemoryAllocation)"

Comment: I hope I'm not driving you in the wrong direction, but I would investigate for a possible driver issue. Are you using the correct driver for your card? What about reinstalling the driver?

Comment: There was an update available for my card, so I have installed it. Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried with a simple system restart? It solved this kind of problems [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/606400/cuda-setup-and-installation/cuda-bandwidthtest-fails-devicequery-passes/), [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/605603/error-for-bandwidth-test-after-install-cuda-in-mac-/#3937632) and [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/605398/cuda-error-at-bandwidthtest-cu-for-geforce-gtx-660m/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved. I'm still not sure what caused this, either there was a conflict between old video card driver and a new one installed hiddenly under "Recommended" option in Cuda installer, or a askew installed VS 2008. However I decided to reinstall everything and try VS 2012 instead of VS 2008, and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a CUDA context, [a lot of stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8686409/1938163) is allocated so it might happen that your available memory isn't enough to intialize it. That might explain the **cudaErrorMemoryAllocation** error you're getting.

**cudaMemGetInfo** doesn't throw that specific error so it must be something else:

> Note that this function may also return error codes from previous,
>   asynchronous launches.

The **cuD3D11CtxCreate** in the stack trace also creates a CUDA context so it might be it.

Also: if you have **multiple apps** running contending your device, that might be the cause as well.

Comment: I think 512 MB should be enough to initialize Cuda environment, there is no other programms running that could consume whole memory.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the device prior to do that? cudaDeviceReset

Comment: I have tried just now. cudaDeviceReset() returns cudaSuccess, but no changes for the rest part of the program