# OpenACC - How to find if device is busy doing some CUDA operations?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, openacc

I have a CUDA-based code and I want to incorporate OpenACC into some parts of the code. But, the function that I am trying to parallelize by OpenACC code sometimes is governed by CUDA calls and sometimes not.

My question is that how can I query OpenACC library to see whether device is busy or not. Is there any API calls for that?

*Note:* I am not completely familiar with CUDA, so I just use pseudo-code.

Sometimes the target function `seq_function` is called on the host when device is busy with computation like below. But, sometimes it is called when device is **not** busy.

```
cudaMemAlloc(...);
cudaLaunchAsync(...);
...
//This is the function I am trying to parallelize with OpenACC
seq_function(...); 
...
cudaWait(...);
cudaDealloc(...);
```

So, I want to make my target function flexible:

- if device is busy or a CUDA-based computation is running => use host.
- if device is **not** busy => use GPU through OpenACC-enabled code.

Is there a way to find whether the device is busy or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to programmatically get the device utilization.  You can get the memory usage via [cudaMemGetInfo](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g376b97f5ab20321ca46f7cfa9511b978) which you might be able to use to extrapolate if something is running on the GPU or not.

Comment: Thanks Mat. Although it is CUDA- and NVidia-specific and not a general method as OpenACC promises, it seems that it is the only way to find out.

Comment: PGI does offer a extensions to the OpenACC API, "acc_get_memory" and "acc_get_free_memory", which essentially does the same thing as cudaMemGetInfo.  I only suggested cudaMemGetInfo given you were using CUDA elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I am using OpenACC with presence of CUDA (while CUDA is also used). I want to add a feature to previously written CUDA-based code. So, having this extension helps a lot and makes my piece of code to be independent.

Comment: But, the thing is that the value returned as the "free" is different from total value at the beginning (as discussed in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684770/how-is-cuda-memory-managed) too. Therefore, there is no way to do so, unless we record free (available) memory from the beginning and compare current free memory with that.

Comment: If you're willing to use concepts specific to NVIDIA accelerators, the NVML api allows you to query device utilization data directly.  Most of what you can retrieve with `nvidia-smi -a` can be retrieved through NVML, the library behind the [GPU deployment kit](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-deployment-kit).  For example `nvmlDeviceGetUtilizationRates()`